# De Facto Reference for Algorithm Performances?

Tags: performance, algorithm

A common theme I'm seeing in my courses are worst/best case performances for trees, hash tables, equations such as log n. I'm wondering if there's a de facto place where people refer to find this sort of information (textbook, online, etc) besides Wikipedia. I'm hoping to find something that mathematically breaks down such algorithms/data structures.

For example something that explains why insertion into a binary heap is O(log2n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knuth's [TAOCP](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/taocp.html). Also [Introduction to Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms). These two books were base to almost all my algorithm courses at my uni. Especially the first one is very math-heavy (it explains the math pretty well, you don't have to have some specific math knowledge beforehand).

Comment: If you're looking for the rigorous mathematical analysis, you can't beat Knuth.

Answer (score 4):

Someone from Stack Overflow linked this to me the other day(I can't find it now). Is this what you're looking for?
http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/dads/

Comment: This is a great resource! Unfortunately I'm looking for something that's much more mathematical. I will clarify this in my question. Thanks again.

Comment: Holy smokes, I didn't know how excited I'd actually get from a database made up of data structures and algorithms. >>

Answer (score 0):

[The Art of Computer Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) from Knuth, is what one can consider as a good reference. If you find errors in these books, you get 2,56$/error (reward check). This reward has been going on over years and you get cited, encouranging the books to become perfect. It breaks down all kinds of algorithms and data structures.